# Nginx: default to the most specific index.html if the specified path isn't found?

Tags: html, nginx

E.g. for the files:

```
dir1/
    index.html
index.html
```

If an user accesses `/dir1/somefile`, load `/dir1/index.html`. If they access `/somefile`, load `/index.html`. A lot of my directories are dynamically generated, so I don't want to hardcode every condition. Is there an easier way to route to the most specific fallback `index.html` file?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can achieve it like this - but I have not tested this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
  rewrite ^(.*)/[^/]$ $1/index.html last;
}
```